# add cron job dynamic in google app

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, scheduled-tasks

In Google app engine, i want to add a task at runtime.

this task will start run at specific time ( for example at 9am, May 20 ).

this task will repeat every 2 minites from that time.

I know that Google app engine have cron task to schedule task.

But my problem is I can't add task to cron task at runtime.

thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use the taskqueue API and set the `eta` parameter to determine when a task will get run. From each task, you can fire off another one to run 2 minutes later.